# TikZ: Change position of arrowhead along line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have a TikZ plotmark and an arrow leading to it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (4,0) {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
  \draw [->] (0,0) -- (4,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both arrow and plotmark should have the same color, so the arrowhead is mostly not visible because it is in the same position as the plot mark.

Is there a way (without having to calculate new coordinates) to position the arrowhead slightly before the end of the line so that the arrowhead touches the plotmark rather than being inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[right=-1.5pt] {\pgfuseplotmark{*}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know your intention, but anyway, see, if arrows.meta library can offer an solution (combination of `{Straight Barb[].Circle[]}` ). In this case you don't need node for circle:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
myarrow/.style = {-{Straight Barb[].Circle[width=3.2pt,length=3.2pt]},
                  shorten >=-1.6pt}
                        ]
\draw [myarrow] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [myarrow] (3,0) -- (3,3);

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second solution also works with diagonal lines, therefore perfect for me (answered my above question). But it seems the end of the line is not the center of the circle. If there should be another line originating from the circle it will look weird since it doesn't come out from the circle's center.

Comment: I reedit my answer to show, how to deal with drawing when lines aren't straight.